# Fibonacci Recursion Equation

Tags: sequences-and-series, recurrence-relations, induction

For the Fibonacci sequence, prove the formula $a^2_{n+1} = a_n a_{n+2} + (-1)^n$ using induction.

I have done the base case, when $n=3$, because for the Fibonacci sequence, $a_1=a_2=1$. I have no idea where to start for the induction piece.

Comment: I suggest that $n=1$ (or even $n=0$?) is the base case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that $a_{k+1}^2=a_ka_{k+2}+(-1)^k$ for $k\le n$, you want to show that $$a_{n+2}^2=a_{n+1}a_{n+2}+(-1)^{n+1}$$ or, equivalently, that $$a_{n+2}^2-a_{n+1}a_{n+2}=(-1)^{n+1}\;.$$ A very straightforward approach is to begin by using the Fibonacci recurrence to expand the lefthand side:

$$\begin{align*}
a_{n+2}^2-a_{n+1}a_{n+3}&=(a_{n+1}+a_n)^2-(a_n+a_{n-1})(a_{n+2}+a_{n+1})\\
&=a_{n+1}^2+2a_{n+1}a_n+a_n^2-a_na_{n+2}-a_na_{n+1}-a_{n-1}a_{n+2}-a_{n-1}a_{n+1}\\
&=(a_{n+1}^2-a_na_{n+2})+(a_n^2-a_{n-1}a_{n+1})+a_{n+1}a_n-a_{n-1}a_{n+2}\\
&=(-1)^n+(-1)^{n-1}+a_{n+1}a_n-a_{n-1}(a_{n+1}+a_n)\;.
\end{align*}$$

Now see if you can simplify that last expression down to $(-1)^{n+1}$. At some point you’ll probably want to use the relationship $a_{n+1}-a_{n-1}=a_n$.

Comment: I'm super stuck. I've tried it at least 3 different ways and just can not seem to get that last expression to $(-1)^{n+1}$. Any thoughts or ideas?

Comment: @Kristen: Did you manage any simplification of it at all? What about the first two terms, for instance?

Comment: If anything, I think I made it more complicated. I've got work on about 10 different sheets of paper that I'm trying to make sense of.

Comment: @Kristen: Okay, let’s start with the easiest bit: what’s $(-1)^n+(-1)^{n-1}$?

Comment: It's zero, right?

Comment: @Kristen: It is indeed. Now multiply out the rest to get $$a_{n+1}a_n-a_{n-1}a_{n+1}-a_{n-1}a_n\;,$$ combine the two terms that contain $a_n$, and see if you can then use the last comment in my answer.

Comment: I think I got it down to $(-1)^{n-1}=(-1)^{n+1}$ which I know is true because $n-1$ and $n+1$ are either both even or both odd. Do I need to prove that part?

Comment: @Kristen: Sounds like you did the right thing, and no, you shouldn’t need to prove that.

Answer (score 0):

*Hint:* Replace $a_{n+1}$ with $a_{n+1}+a_n$ and one of the $a_{n+1}$ on the left with $a_n+a_{n-1}$.

Comment: So, are you saying that I should assume that it is true for $a^2_{n+1}$ and then use that to prove that it is true for $a^2_{n+2}$? I was starting by assuming it was true for $a_n$.